# Can't print a specific cell from sql query

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm having trouble with my php code. I have a table in my DB and every entry has a name, type, location etc. The basic idea is that after entering the name from the previous page (that's why there's a POST variable at the start of the code), you get transfered to this page and it prints the corresponding type. The problem is that even though I'm sure the code is correct and I've tried a few different solutions (I've been searching for a while in the forum), I can't print the type variable.

```
<?php 

$k = $_POST['sub1'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","qr code");

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT type FROM array1 WHERE name ='".$k."'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo $row['type'];  }

?>
```

Any ideas? It's probably a very simple solution, but I'm totally stuck now so I'm sorry if it's too basic :P

Comment: result of `var_dump($k);` and `var_dump($row['type']);`?

Comment: The result of var_dump($k) is the correct string that's entered from the previous page, but the result of var_dump($row['type']) is NULL...

Comment: Please check your query.

Comment: now you know why there is no output ;)

Comment: Yes I do lol, but I can't figure out what I've done wrong ...

Comment: @user131758 - check your query, check if the type is NULL on database, check using the right table, etc.. we don't see the data so we can't help you on this point

Comment: ok, I'm using the right table and the type is INT on the DB. I'm not sure about the query, particularly after the WHERE clause... Is that part correct?

Comment: @user131758 Do you have any output at all? Have you tried running the query directly in the database with the value you get from var_dump($k). That would allow you to rule out the query as the source of the issue.

Comment: It runs fine directly in the database I don't get any results in the browser, only null

Comment: Move the query into a variable, echo the query - copy query into your gui for the database (phpMyAdmin etc). What happens then?

Comment: Mmm, that database name 'qr code' does the database have a space? Increase the error level of your script. Might show something 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');    
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

Comment: The query runs fine in the phpMyAdmin and shows the correct results. I'm not sure what you mean in the beginning of the sentence(before the "-") and I don't know how to do that. Yeah there's a space in the database's title, but I don't think that's the problem

Comment: I mean $query = "SELECT type FROM array1 WHERE name ='".$k."'";
echo $query;

Comment: ok the result of the echo command is: SELECT type FROM array1 WHERE name ='Cafe'. I copied and ran it directly in phpmyadmin and it shows the correct results.

Comment: Ok, so after some tests, it successfully echoes the types of the names that are in english, but it won't echo the types of the names that are in greek. It's problably an encoding issue, but all my tables and code files are in utf-8  and even though I included mysql_set_charset('utf8');
 in this file, I still have the problem.

Comment: I fixed it. I had to include mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8'); Thank you all :)